# change global css element

Tags: css, reactjs, gsap

i've made this banner like screen that appears when my site is loaded, but here's the thing, i don't want no scrollbar while this opening animation it's happening, i only want to show the other components (the scrollbar and the whole site) once the gsap animation finishes, how could i proceed? thanks! (i tried to create a function to control those global elements, is it a way?)

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: Please include the whole code in the question. As a suggestion you could set `overflow:hidden` on a parent div of the animation, so that you won't get scrollbars when the animation elements are off screen.

Comment: Add the relevant code to the question. Images don't count!

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly you need the Banner to be displayed until the site is loaded. Maybe you are making some API calls or in general, you are planning to show the banner for let's say 3 sec and post that you want your actual components to be displayed.

You can try below approch:

```
export const APP = (): JSX.Element => {

const [isAnimationInProgress, SetAnimationState] = React.useState(true);

React.useEffect(() => {
// You can have your page load API calls done here
// Or wait for 'X' seconds
// Post that set the AnimationState to false to render actual components
setAnimationState(false);
})

return (
     {   
       isAnimationInProgress && <Banner />
     }
     {
       !isAnimationInProgress && <ActualComponent />
     }
)
}
```

Regarding scrollbars, including `overflow: hidden;` in style for the banner should do the work if you are getting scrollbars for the Banner component.